# How much of the manga did the anime adaptation of The World Is Still Beautiful cover?

Tags: the-world-is-still-beautiful

I want to read the manga *Soredemo Sekai wa Utsukushii* where the anime left off, but I'm not sure where it did.

Answer (score 1):

It leaves off at chapter 19  so you want to start  on chapter 20.

Answer (score 1):

It covers the first 19 chapters.

[Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E3%81%AF%E7%BE%8E%E3%81%97%E3%81%84#.E5.90.84.E8.A9.B1.E3.83.AA.E3.82.B9.E3.83.88) has a list of the episodes including the corresponding manga chapters:

> - *Episode 1: **Original**, Chapter 1*
> - Episode 2: Chapter 1
> - Episode 3: Chapter 1, 2
> - Episode 4: Chapter 4, 5
> - Episode 5: Chapter 5, 6
> - *Episode 6: **Chapter 3***
> - Episode 7: Chapter 7, 8
> - Episode 8: Chapter 9, 10
> - Episode 9: Chapter 11, 12
> - Episode 10: Chapter 13-15
> - Episode 11: Chapter 15-17
> - Episode 12: Chapter 18, 19

However, according to [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/22101/Soredemo_Sekai_wa_Utsukushii),

> An original ending was written for the Soredemo Sekai wa Utsukushii anime.